# multy operators in raw input not work

Tags: python

I try to make some bot and i stack with multyple operators for if. here is the part of script :

```
def start() :
  print
ans=True
while ans:
    print
    ans=raw_input(": User : ")
    if ans=="A":
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Syst :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
    else:
         print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
         print
         time.sleep(2)
         start()
```

in this line : if ans=="A": i want to use multyple operators : i can do it like this :

```
def start() :
  print
ans=True
while ans:
    print
    ans=raw_input(": User : ")
    if ans=="A":
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Syst :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
    elif ans=="B":
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Syst :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
    elif ans=="C":
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Syst :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
    else:
         print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
         print
         time.sleep(2)
         start()
```

its not good for me becous its be to mach long ... i need it be like this :

```
      if ans==("A","B","C"):
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Syst :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
```

and its not work .. there is some mistake in sintax .. i cant make it work 
please exuse me , my english is not so good .

Comment: 1) `if ans == "A" or ans == "B" or ans == "C":`  2) `if ans in "ABC":`  please edit your post its hard to understand what you want exactly

Comment: This work for me : if ans == "A" or ans == "B" or ans == "C":      . Perfect !!!! you are my Hero !!!

Comment: glad you found what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

here the solution thanks to Tanmay Jain

```
if ans=="A" or ans == "B" or ans == "C":
         WORDS = ("A", "B", "C")
         word = random.choice(WORDS)
         print
         print ": Iqar :", word
         time.sleep(1)
         start()
```